# Stopping RMI Server (Java)

Tags: java, rmi

I created a sucessful RMI server, thank god for that :)

It works perfectly..
I have a JForm and it gets activated clicking on a button.

Altough i wanted to create too a button to deactivate it, but i am having a problems to unexport it.

Ok then and this is the way i was trying to exporting and terminating the RMI Server

```
private void btStopServerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
 try {
            // Nome do objecto
            String objectname = txtObjectName.getText();
            // obtem o número da porta
            int port = Integer.parseInt(txtServerPort.getText());

            RemoteMessageObject remote = new RemoteMessageObject();
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
            UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port), true);
            registry.unbind(objectname);


            System.out.println("Server offline");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I get this exception:

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not exported
```

at the line:

```
UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port), true);
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Solved................

I discovered it before :P
Anywway thanks @EJP for the correct answer.

So the solution for me was to create the Register when the class starts as a public variable, so it could be use inside both click events (Start server and stop server).

I removed too a lot of nonsense stuff that was not necessary for disabling the RMI server just like @EJP sayed.

Its now working this way:

```
private void btStopServerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    try {
        // Nome do objecto
        String objectname = txtObjectName.getText();
        // obtem o número da porta
        int port = Integer.parseInt(txtServerPort.getText());

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port);
        UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this.registry, true);
        registry.unbind(objectname);

        System.out.println("Server offline");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        GuiUtils.addText(txtLog, "Erro", "Servidor desligado");
        btStopServer.setEnabled(false);
        btStartServer.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (NotBoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ServerGUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "problems". Exception? Stack Trace? Nothing happens?

Comment: @Marvin java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: object not exported at the line:
"UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(LocateRegistry.getRegistry(port), true);"

Comment: You *still* havent unexported your own remote object, which was the point of the entire question. Clients can still call it, if they already have the stub from a prior `lookup().` The message saying 'server offline' is therefore false. NB The `getRegistry()` call in your new code is pointless, and if you succeed in unexporting the registry, there is no need to call `unbind()` at all.

Comment: @EJP you are a life savier, in fact, the unbind and all the code that i had really prevents from more people to login to the remote connection.

Altough, like you sayed, people that were already was logged in to it, even with the server offline, they could still use the remote methods.

Thanks a lot.
I have just now a couple of bugs, but i will try to fix it, on my own. I will update the main post later to not spread misinformation.

Comment: Claiming they can't login is incorrect. They can call any method if they already have the stub. The unbind is pointless because the registry has ceased to exist. All you have to do is unexport the Registry and the object.

Comment: They were connecting :D

Its fixed now.

All i've donewas to unexport the remote.
I declared a remote on the startup of the class and then claimed on the start server that a remote = new remoteMessageObject()

On the stopServer i unexport the remote.
Altough if i stopped the server and started again through the buttons, i was getting an exception related to the ObjID, so i had to get the registry and unexport the registry and unbind (maybe some of the lines are pointless), i will investigate further altough it fixed the fact that the server couldn't start up after being stopped. Thanks.

Comment: The unbind line *is* pointless after unexporting the Registry. No 'maybe' about it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unexport the object returned by `LocateRegistry.createRegistry().` The object returned by `getRegistry()` isn't the actual `Registry` object, it is a stub, and you can't unexport those.

But unexporting the Registry and then calling `unbind()` doesn't make sense. Doing it the other way round makes a little sense, but not much.

And you also have to unexport your own remote object.

And creating a new remote object in a method that is trying to unexport the existing one doesn't make sense either.